# My RDP is disconnecting my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop when I disconnects display cable of Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I'm learning and using Ubuntu desktop version(LTS) for many years, around couple of weeks I'm facing the below RDP issues..

Problem facing "**Unable to connect RDP my Ubuntu 20.04 when display (VGA cable) removes from my Ubuntu 20.04 machine**"

Using 2 machines:

1. Windows-10 laptop (wifi connected) same network (ip: 192.168.03)
2. Ubuntu 20.04 desktop version in my Lenovo workstation (separate machine) ethernet connected (same network) (ip: 192.16.0.2)

Both machines are connected in the same network and I can connect RDP from "Windows-10 to Ubuntu 20.04" and can work for several hours, the problem is when I removes the Display Port (VGA cable) from the Ubuntu machine RDP session disconnects and unable to take RDP without connect VGA cable but the Ubuntu is up and running and its pinging with out any packet drops.

Some time I need two monitors (multiple display) in my laptop as per my work requires, so I disconnected the VGA cable from Ubuntu machine and I'll connected it to my Laptop (Windows-10) to extend the displays.

The Ubuntu machine (ip- 192.168.0.2) is pinging whether the display port connected or unplugged the VGA while the Ubuntu machine is up and running, the only thing is I can't take RDP with out the VGA (display cable) connected

Please help me on this..

[Ubuntu machine is pings with out any packet drops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv9pi.png)